# How to initialize WebElements in Selenium page object

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am new to Selenium and looking forward to learn more, I am using Selenium WebDriver with C#.

This is how I initiate a `WebElement`:

```
CarouselSliderNextButton = DriverInitializer.driver
        .FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@class='buttons next']"));
```

But if the element doesn't exist for some reason; hidden for instance, then it doesn't work. I know that I can check if the element exists before I can initiate, but would love to hear from experts if I am doing this the right way.

Answer (score 0):

I am not claiming to be an expert, but this is what I think:

- You do not "initiate" a web element
- You find a web element
- First of all, you need to find the element you want to locate from html file. You may use Google or Firefox in developer mode to find it. I recommend you to install "Firebug" for Firefox, it is very useful.
- There are multiple reasons why an element you can "see" from HTML file but you can not locate:
- 1: this element is on an iframe, this case requires you to locate this iframe first then locate the element
- 2: this element is not visible yet, for example, a drop down arrow button will only appear if you hover your mouse over a certain area first.

But you are heading to the right direction.

Comment: Thanks Yu Zhang i appreciate the contribution , was more hoping to understund how i can find the webelements and declare them as lets say variables for my page object class, as for now , for example if  i do simply like this ;CarouselSliderNextButton = DriverInitializer.driver
        .FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@class='buttons next']")); -and the element doesn't appear in the HTML page yet then i get an exception , so i am declaring this variables inside a method to be able to handle such exceptions

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to intialise the WebElement, I use:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.tagName("div"));
```

as most DOMs have div tags.
Then after trying to find an element that exists (and isn't a div tag), check:

```
if (element.getTagName().equals("div")){
    System.out.println("Element not found...");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`var instantEstimateDiv: WebElement? = null` => Kotlin

`WebElement? instantEstimateDiv=  null;` => JAVA

Comment: Mehdi Benkirane, while this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.

Comment: My response is direct answer of post "How to initialize WebElements in Selenium page object?" if 1st graders were checking results, I would formulate the answer as follow:
To initialize a WebElement in Selenium page, you do the following ...
without this last sentence, my answer is ambiguous or not clear, is it what you are refering @LucaKiebel? or just need for something to say really curious :)